# Did Krishna take avatar from womb of Mata Devki?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, avatars

Did Krishna take avatar from womb of a woman, or Did he appear outside of the womb ?

What does Mahabharata, ShriMad Bhagvad Purana and Brahma Vairvata Purana tells about it. I think these historical scripture and Purans are solely dedicated to Krishna. So, they must have description about his birth.

Comment: I think he took avatara from womb as mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26969)

Comment: Not being born from the womb of a woman, there is a term for it in Sanskrit, *ayonija*, *Ayonija* simply means one who isn't born from *yoni* (uterus, womb). In none of the itihāsa texts is Kr̥ṣṇa said to be *ayonija*, he is always shown to have had a normal birth (from womb) as per my knowledge. Draupadī, who is also known by the name Kr̥ṣṇā, was *ayonija* though. 
If you are interested in *ayonija* and unnatural births in epics, I wrote an answer on it  
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53555/24460